# DataGridComboBoxColumn с разным набором items

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, combobox

Имеется DataGrid, в нем несколько колонок и 1 DataGridComboBoxColumn, хотелось бы для каждого DataGridComboBoxColumn видеть различный набор элементов Xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TeplateView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TemplateGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="19,48,19,97">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SecondName"  Binding="{Binding SecondName}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="VersionCMB" Header="Version" ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
public class TeplateView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SvnLogEventArgs> Versions { get; set; }

}
```

Решил проблему следующим способом:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Versions">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomisedUIElement Text="{Binding Path=Versions}"/> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Но задаюсь вопросом, правильно ли это?

Comment: решил проблему следующим способом

Comment: `<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Versions">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <local:CustomisedUIElement Text="{Binding Path=Versions}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>`

Comment: но задаюсь вопросом, правильно ли это?

Comment: Мне вообще не нравится `DataGridComboBoxColumn`  из за его ограниченности. Использую в основном `DataGridTemplateColumn`

Comment: а первый вариант почему не подошел?

Comment: Первый вариант обращается к коллекции, к которой он не имеет доступа, поэтому не получается корректно сбиндится, во втором доступ к ней есть

Comment: @АлексейАлексеев, ну так вам надо подняться до DataContext окна, например: `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Versions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"`